# jQuery ajaxStart bound with unique element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#innerDiv1").ajaxStart(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id") + " ajaxStart");
        });

        $("#innerDiv2").ajaxStart(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id") + " ajaxStart");
        });

        $("#button").click(function () {
            $.post("test.aspx");
        });

        $("#button1").click(function () {
            $.post("test.aspx");
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that whenever I click the "button" or "button1" both ajaxStart events are invoked even though the ajaxStart handlers are bound with unique elements

I would like to invoke only one ajaxStart, the one according to which button I click on, is this possible?

UPDATE...

After reading the answers and also finding out that it is not possible...can anyone explain the reason why the ajaxStart can be bound with an element??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ajaxStart` is a global Ajax event.. that means that all ajaxStart events you bind will be triggered in each Ajax call you make..

quoting from http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. **Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at this time.**

If you want something different for each call then just do what you want in the button click..

something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            $("#innerDiv1").html('start of 1');
            $.post("test.aspx");
        });

        $("#button1").click(function () {
            $("#innerDiv2").html('start of 2');
            $.post("test.aspx");
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

**update**

how about

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showProgress(elementId){
      $('#' + elementId).append('<div class="progress"></div>');
    }
    function hideProgress(elementId){
      $('#' + elementId).find('.progress').remove();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            var id = 'innerDiv1';
            showProgress( id );
            $.post("test.aspx", function(){hideProgress( id );});
        });

        $("#button1").click(function () {
            var id = 'innerDiv2';
            showProgress( id );
            $.post("test.aspx", function(){hideProgress( id );});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am using this ajaxStart to show a loading bar by appending html to the parent div of $(this), that's why I would need the ajaxStart and obviously ajaxStop later on

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything passed to `ajaxStart` allowing you to know what ajax request was started. But since both of your buttons are starting the same request, I suppose that wouldn't help you anyway.

Your best bet is probably just to handle the distinction in your button `click` handlers, rather than trying to handle it in your `ajaxStart` handlers.

But if you really want to do it in the `ajaxStart` handlers, you could use a flag variable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ajaxRequestedBy;

    $("#innerDiv1").ajaxStart(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id") + " ajaxStart");
    });

    $("#innerDiv2").ajaxStart(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id") + " ajaxStart");
    });

    $("#button").click(function () {
        ajaxRequestedBy = this;
        $.post("test.aspx");
    });

    $("#button1").click(function () {
        ajaxRequestedBy = this;
        $.post("test.aspx");
    });
});
```

Problems with that:

- You'll want a way to clear that flag variable so you don't have references to DOM elements lying around. (E.g., a global `ajaxComplete` handler.)
- You may well want to avoid setting it if it's already set.
- It tightly couples the buttons to the `ajaxStart` handlers, suggesting that there's a better structural approach.

Comment: But this would still invoke both ajaxStart handlers

Comment: @Ryan: Right. And you would use the `ajaxRequestedBy` in them to figure out whether to do anything.

Comment: In fact I have just tested it right now and looks good, what I did was registered the $(document).ajaxStart(function(){}); is this what you meant by the variable ajaxRequestedBy?

Comment: @Ryan: No, I meant what I wrote in the code. Then in the `ajaxStart` handlers, you would examine the `ajaxRequestedBy` variable to see which button was pressed. But that's **not** what I'm recommending above. What I'm recommending above is *"...just to handle the distinction in your button click handlers, rather than trying to handle it in your `ajaxStart` handlers."* @Gaby's saying much the same thing.